# Show that the map $\varphi:K \to L, \ \ (x,t) \mapsto (x,t^2)$ is a proper holomorphic map.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, line-bundles

> Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle on $X$. We assume that there exist a holomorphic line bundle $K$ on $X$ and an isomorphism $$K^{\otimes 2} \cong L.$$ Show that the map $$\varphi:K \to L, \ \ (x,t) \mapsto (x,t^2)$$ is a holomorphic map.

It's been a while since I've done anything related to bundle maps, but I have a feeling that this can be proven locally using local trivializations and transition functions, but I'm not able to devise a plan on how to use these.

Could someone provide me guidance on how to use these tools to prove the statement?

Comment: Your instincts are good. Maybe write the transition equation for a local section of $K$ in the form $t_{\beta} = g_{\alpha\beta} t_{\alpha}$ (or whatever notation you prefer), then square both sides, keeping in mind everyone is a locally-defined _complex-valued_ function.

Comment: Properness is a separate issue …

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I started to question myself on whether I actually need to even check the holomorphicity condition since the map $(x,t) \mapsto (x,t^2)$ consists of the identity and the map $t \mapsto t^2$ which are both holomorphic locally. Is there something else I should be considering?

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah yes that's true. The question actually had two parts and I forgot to remove the part for properness from this.

Comment: Just to note: It's necessary to show the proposed local representations of mappings glue together with the stated global codomain. That's why it's necessary to work with transition functions. (As for the formula $\varphi(x, t) = (x, t^{2})$, some explanation is required since $t$ is not strictly a complex number/global coordinate on $K$.)